# Get correct negative value for int containing a signed byte

Tags: python, int, byte, signed

I'm receiving a bytearray containing, in one position, a signed byte.

I know that bytearray is really an array of ints, so when I index the position I'm interested in I get an int back.  If:

```
myByteArray[5] = 0b11111110
```

Python treats this as decimal 254, presumably because it is storing the value as a 32 bit int:

```
00000000 00000000 00000000 11111110
```

As I understand it, all python ints are signed, so this is a signed 32 bit int, but it's storing my signed 8 bit int in it's lowest byte...  How do I get my signed value back?